# Typescript filter out keys from object based on a type

Tags: typescript

I am using graphql and codegen. When I am using a mutation, I would like to remove keys that are not in the type PartyBaseInput. I tried to do something using lodash pick

```js
input = pick(dataWithMoreKeysThenInPartyBaseInput, Object.keys(PartyBaseInput));
```

But get:

```
'PartyBaseInput' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Does this article help? https://www.breck-mckye.com/blog/2020/10/TypeScript-accessing-members-of-a-union-type/ . You can apply the technique to get union type members to the union type `keyof PartyBaseInput`

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something like `keyof`. If you want to use it by `Object.keys()` then first create a variable `partyBase=PartyBaseInput` then do `Object.keys(partyBase))`. Now how `partyBase` is to be initialized, would depend on if its a class or interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using https://github.com/YousefED/typescript-json-schema and https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv . I generate a json schema from TypeScript definitions and use ajv to remove keys not in the schema. The TypeScript definitions are generated with https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator from a graphql schema. Many steps

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try..

*Initialize object* of the class so that it can take keys from created ***Object***. ( Assuming **`PartyBaseInput`** is of type Class)

```
input = pick(dataWithMoreKeysThenInPartyBaseInput, Object.keys( new PartyBaseInput() ));
```

Comment: If its a type or interface then?

Comment: In my case it was a type